# Filtering SQL Database to DataGridView with one textbox and Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datagridview

I have a single `textbox` that filters all columns of my `SQL Database Table`. The filtering is triggered with a `button` called `FilterIDLS`.

```
private void filterIDLS_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txt = keyIDLS.Text;

        if (txt != "")
        {
            _db.conn();
            _db.cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.IncomingLog WHERE
                                [Date Received] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Reference Number] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Time Received] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Title/Description] LIKE '%{0}%' OR 
                                [Received Copies] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Originating Office] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Received Person] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Filed Under] LIKE '%{0}%' OR
                                [Encoded By] LIKE '%{0}%'" + keyIDLS.Text;

            dt = _db.executeDT();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type a keyword to search!", "Nothing to Search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (incomLogTableS.RowCount == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No records from the database found. Please try again.", "0 Records Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

There are no errors when I save the solution. But when I Debug it, it points to this:

```
public DataTable executeDT()
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable("DataTable");
        adapter.Fill(datatable);

        adapter.Update(datatable);

        return datatable;
    }
```

And says an SQLException was unhandled and it has Incorrect syntax near 'PRS' (The keyword I typed on the textbox.)

What will I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typed n time the {0} placeholder for the string format functionality but you never called string.Format(string, arguments) to correctly format your string.

```
_db.cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT ......", keyIDLS.Text);
```

However this approach (string.Format) is not the correct one when building sql commands. Instead you use parameters to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and parsing problems with string containing single quotes.

```
_db.cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.IncomingLog WHERE
                    [Date Received] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Reference Number] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Time Received] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Title/Description] LIKE @p1 OR 
                    [Received Copies] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Originating Office] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Received Person] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Filed Under] LIKE @p1 OR
                    [Encoded By] LIKE @p1"
 List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>()
 {
    new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar) {Value = keyIDLS.Text}
 };
 dt = _db.executeDT(prms);

.....
public DataTable executeDT(List<SqlParameter> prms = null)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable("DataTable");
    if(prms != null) 
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
    adapter.Fill(datatable);
    return datatable;
}
```

Let me say also that your query could work correctly only if all your columns are of type NVarChar. A lot of fields seems to be of different datatype so it will be impossible to get meaningful result from a query that uses the same value to search both in DateTime, Numbers and Text fields.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Also, all of the columns are of `nvarchar` data type, I just named them like that.